# adding time to an POSIXct based on conditional statement

Tags: r

I have the data frame below

If the hour of time3 is 12 then I'd like to add 1 hour to time2. When I do that the result comes back numeric and not a POSIXct.  How can I make this work?

```
dat = data.frame(
  time1 = as.POSIXct(c("2016-01-01 00:00:00")), 
  time2 =as.POSIXct(c("2016-02-02 10:10:10")) ,
   time3 =as.POSIXct(c("2016-02-02 12:30:30")) 
  ) 
dat
class(dat$time1)
class(dat$time2)
dat$test = ifelse(as.numeric(format(dat$time3, format = "%H") ) == 12, dat$time2+3600, dat$time1)
dat
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some alternatives:

**1) replace**

```
transform(dat, test = replace(time1, as.POSIXlt(time3)$hour == 12, time2 + 3600))
```

**2) arithmetic**

```
transform(dat, test = time1 + (as.POSIXlt(time3)$hour == 12) * (time2 - time1 + 3600))
```

**2) dplyr::if_else**

```
dat %>% mutate(test = if_else(as.POSIXlt(time3)$hour == 12, time2 + 3600, time1))
```